# Store reference values in an array

Tags: c

i cant figure out how to store the phone variable into the array and have it printed in the first switch statement. Every time i run the code it takes the last element that was entered and ignores the rest.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 3

void decompose(long long int n, int *area, int *prefix, int *line) {

    int n1, n2, n3;

    n1 = n / 10000000;
    n2 = (n / 10000) % 1000;
    n3 = (n / 1) % 10000;

    *area = n1;
    *prefix = n2;
    *line = n3;
}

/* main program */ 
int main(void) {

    int option;
    int phone, num;
    int aaa, ppp, llll;
    int i = 0;
    long long int phoneNumber[size] = {0LL, 0LL, 0LL};


    printf("---=== Phone Numbers ===---\n\n");

    do {
        // Display the Option List
        printf("1. Display Phone List\n");
        printf("2. Add a Number\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Please select from the above options: ");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        printf("\n");

        switch (option) {

            case 0: // Exit the program
                printf("Exiting Phone Number App. Good Bye!!!");
                break;

            case 1: // Display the Phone List
                    // @IN-LAB
                printf("Phone Numbers\n");
                printf("==============\n");
                // Display each number in decomposed form
                for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    printf("(%3d)-%3d-%4d", aaa, ppp, llll);
                    printf("\n");
                }
                break;

            case 2: // Add a Phone Number
                    // @IN-LAB
                printf("Add a Number\n");
                printf("============\n");
                scanf("%d", &phone);

                for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                    decompose(phone, &aaa, &ppp, &llll);
                    phoneNumber[i] = phone;
                }

            default:
                printf("Invalid menu option\n");
                break;
        }

    } while (option != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a phone number you split it up into the constituent parts and save them into `aaa`, `ppp` and `llll`. You then save the full number into all 3 elements of `phoneNumber`. Every thing you enter a new number you'll repeat that process, overwriting the previous contents of all of those variables.

From looking at your code you could make parallel arrays for the area code, prefix and line values. Or, better, create a `struct` that contains those fields, such as:

```
struct phoneNumber {
  int areaCode;
  int prefix;
  int line;
}
```

And make an array of those structures: `struct phoneNumber phoneNumbers[size]`. When you enter a new phone number, save the pieces/parts into the last unused entry in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I see what u mean it only references the address not the actual remainder of the number. Why is that if my decompose variables are referencing aaa, ppp, llll. It seems to work when it is in the main but when i move it to the decompse function it screws everything up.

Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate you taking time to answer my questions and explain what each thing does.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Please save the mods some work and delete this. Answers are not for comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem displaying the phone numbers -- is **"what number are you displaying?"** You need to decompose the number to display it. Currently you are decomposing nothing before attempting to print it. You need something along the lines of:

```
        case 1:                // Display the Phone List
            // @IN-LAB
            printf ("Phone Numbers\n");
            printf ("==============\n");
            // Display each number in decomposed form
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (!(phone = phoneNumber[i]))
                    break;
                decompose (phone, &aaa, &ppp, &llll);
                printf ("(%3d)-%3d-%4d", aaa, ppp, llll);
                printf ("\n");
            }
            break;
```

(you should also be using `unsigned` types to display as you cannot have a *negative* component of the phone number...)

Similarly, taking input you need to protect against attempting to add values to a full array (you can choose how you respond). Which slot are you going to put the number in?? You are not keeping track of how many numbers are currently in the array. There are many ways to do this, but one simple one (available since you initialized the array elements to zero) is to simply loop over your array and check for `0` and fill that slot. You also want to fully validate input every time you take user input. That means checking for `EOF` to determine if the user **cancels** input with <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> (on windoze). Doing that, you could do something similar to:

```
    long long int phone;
    ....
        case 2:                // Add a Phone Number
            // @IN-LAB

            for (i = 0; i < size; i++)  /* check for next open slot */
                if (!phoneNumber[i])
                    break;

            if (i == size)  /* if list full, throw error */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: list full.\n");
            else {
                int rtn = 0;    /* capture scanf return to check EOF */

                printf ("Add a Number\n");
                printf ("============\n");

                /* always validate input */
                if ((rtn = scanf ("%lld", &phone)) == 1)
                    phoneNumber[i] = phone;
                else if (rtn == EOF) {  /* user canceled with ctrl+d (or z) */
                    fprintf (stderr, "NOTE: user canceled input, exiting.\n");
                    return 0; 
                }
                else    /* user entered something stupid */
                    fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            }

            break;  /* don't fall-through default */
```

One other consideration is to empty the `input buffer` (e.g. `stdin`) between the various input, as the user could enter `abc` which would cause all types of havoc with your next `scanf` call. To empty the buffer, simply scan until `'\n'` or `EOF` is found, e.g.:

```
do {
    int c = 0;
    ....
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {} /* empty input buffer */

} while (option != 0);
```

Finally your `decompose` function is suspect. Check the algorithm to insure it is correct. Let me know if you need further help.

---

**Reason Your `decompose` isn't Working**

You are mixing `long long int` with `int` and overflowing `phone`. For example `phoneNumber` is an array of `long long int`, yet you read an `int` into `phone`. To fix the problem you need:

```
long long int phone;
```

and then you need to read a `long long int` with `scanf`, e.g.:

```
if ((rtn = scanf ("%lld", &phone)) == 1)  /* always validate input */
```

**note:** the `%lld`.

**Example Use/Output**

```
Please select from the above options: 2

Add a Number
============
8885551212
1. Display Phone List
2. Add a Number
0. Exit

Please select from the above options: 1

Phone Numbers
==============
(888)-555-1212
1. Display Phone List
2. Add a Number
0. Exit

Please select from the above options: 0

Exiting Phone Number App. Good Bye!!!
```